# Read a file line by line and insert data in to variables and arrays

Tags: c++

```
VA301
20/02/2020 10:20
COLOMBO
SINGAPORE
10 E AB
15 E CDE
22 E ADF
31 E BCF
35 E ABCD
45 E AB
50 E DEF
```

These are the details in my file. I want to read this file line by line and store 1st 5 lines into a variable and other lines into 3 char arrays.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: What did you try ? What is your issue ? SO is not a free coding service. Moreover, details are missing (how do you plan to split the "other lines" in 3 arrays for example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c)

Comment: It looks like you want to read the first 4-lines into into members of an outer `struct` and the rest into a `std::vector<inner_struct>` member. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the "How do I do it?" questions where there are a multitude of approaches that can be taken to read and store the data. A C++ approach would be as described above and [Read Location Data](https://susepaste.org/46591390) which is a simple class implementation taking advantage of the overload of `>>` and `<<` to read and output the class data. It would be a "sane" approach to take with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you really want to do so. If you can give me a better explanation, I can give you a better answer.

To read form file you have to use a file stream input.
Example:

```
ifstream infile("thefile.txt");// change thefile to your file name and make sure it's at the same folder with the programe
```

Now you can use `getline()` method to get data from the stream.

```
string line;
char ch[200];
getline(infile, line);//this to store the line into a string
getline(infile,line,'&'); // the last parameter is the "delimiter"
    //getline() will use delimiter to decide when to stop reading data.
infile.getline(ch,200);  //this to store the line into a char array
```

And simply you can read to the of the file using a loop and `eof()` method

```
while (infile.eof( ))//Mean read until the end of file
{
  //do something 
}
```

To get everything together:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
ifstream infile("thefile.txt");// change thefile to your file name and make sure it's at the same folder with the programe
   string line, var="";
while (infile.eof( ))//Mean read until the end of file
{
    getline(infile, line);//this to store the line into a string
    var= var + line +'\n';
}
//assuming that they are just 3 other lines
char ch1[200],ch2[200],ch3[200];//you can choose another size
    infile.getline(ch1,200);
    infile.getline(ch2,200);
    infile.getline(ch3,200);

}
```

For more information you can read: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_files_streams.htm

Comment: Well this appends all lines to `var`. Question wants just first 5 lines, then put the others in `char` array for some reason

Comment: I edited it so it does what he wants.

Comment: @user4581301 I added more explanation, and references to read from. What else can I do?

Comment: Much improved, but watch out for [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: What should I do when I have 2 or more data sets in my file? Think above set is a data set in my file and each set is separated by a blank line. Ex:                  
VA301
20/02/2020 10:20
COLOMBO
SINGAPORE
10 E AB
15 E CDE
22 E ADF
31 E BCF
35 E ABCD
45 E AB
50 E DEF
****************************
VA532
25/02/2020 12:25
COLOMBO
NEW DELHI
5 B AE
9 B CDE
11 E AF
16 E ABC
23 E DE
29 E DEF
31 E ACE
39 E CDEF
43 E ABC
50 E BCDE

Comment: If you know how many lines you want to read before the blank line, you can easily put a second loop which loops exactly the number of lines before the blank space.
example:

int n=5;//read 5 lines
while (infile.eof( ))//Mean read until the end of file
{
for(int i=0;i<n:i++){
    getline(infile, line);//this to store the line into a string
}
getline(infile, line);//ignore it here
//or use infile.ignore();
}